# Any recommendations for a good online lecture series on Metamorphic Petrology

Tags: reference-request, metamorphism

Any recommendations for a good online lecture series on Metamorphic Petrology?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**[ClassCentral.com](https://www.classcentral.com/course/swayam-metamorphic-petrology-thermodynamics-14197), [SouthAlabama.Edu](https://www.southalabama.edu/geography/allison/gy303/GY303Lectures.html), [ndsu.com](https://www.ndsu.edu/pubweb/%7Esainieid/pet/pet-links.html), [ocw.mit.edu](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/earth-atmospheric-and-planetary-sciences/12-109-petrology-fall-2005/lecture-notes/)**

You can learn a lot from these sites.